# Deserialize a Json Response

Tags: c#, json-deserialization

I'm trying to access the data in a JSON response. My response looks something like this:

```
{
  "vstatus": {
    "id": "gss56jdhh73jj",
    "lockStatus": {
      "value": "LOCKED",
      "status": "CURRENT",
      "timestamp": "07-16-2021 06:50:27"
    },
    "alarm": {
      "value": "SET",
      "status": "CURRENT",
      "timestamp": "07-16-2021 06:50:27"
    },
    "PrmtAlarmEvent": {
      "value": "Null",
      "status": "CURRENT",
      "timestamp": "07-16-2021 06:50:27"
    }
  },
  "version": "4.0.0",
  "status": 200
}
```

I am using the following to deserialize it:

```
var outApiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(receivedData);
```

Then the class's I made are as follows: If I remove the List in the first Class (`ApiResponse`) then this works fine for the status and version. But if I add the list's I get a serializer exception that says it failed to serialize the response into the table.

```
public class ApiResponse
{
   [JsonProperty("vstatus")]
    public List<Items> Vehiclestatus { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("version")]
    public string VersionNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status200 { get; set; }
}

public class Items
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string IDNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lockStatus")]
    public List<LockItems> LockStatus { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("alarm")]
    public List<AlarmItems> AlarmStatus { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("PrmtAlarmEvent")]
    public List<PAlarmItems> PAlarmStatus { get; set; }
}

public class LockItems
{
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string LockValue { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ststus")]
    public string LockCurrent { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public string LockTimeCurrent { get; set; }
}

public class AlarmItems
{
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string AlarmValue { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ststus")]
    public string AlarmCurrent { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public string AlarmTimeCurrent { get; set; }
}

public class PAlarmItems
{
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string PAlarmValue { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ststus")]
    public string PAlarmCurrent { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public string PAlarmTimeCurrent { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an array in your JSON so it fails trying to deserialise into a list. You can fix the C# objects by realising that each item in the sub-object has the same properties so is the same object, meaning you can do this:

```
public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string AlarmCurrent { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

So now the rest of your objects would be:

```
public class ApiResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("vstatus")]
    public VehicleStatus VehicleStatus { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("version")]
    public string VersionNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status200 { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleStatus
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string IDNumber { get; set; }

    // One property for each sub-object here:

    [JsonProperty("lockStatus")]
    public Item LockStatus { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("alarm")]
    public Item AlarmStatus { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("PrmtAlarmEvent")]
    public Item PAlarmStatus { get; set; }
}
```

And use your result like this:

```
var paAlarmCurrent = outApiResponse.VehicleStatus.PAlarmStatus.AlarmCurrent;
```

Comment: Thanks David really appreciate your help.

Comment: If it helps, consider voting and accepting answers.